# Listing 'at' jobs with custom time format

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, timestamps, at

Hello I need to list 'at' jobs with the following format **"year-month-day  hours:minutes:seconds"**. From the 'at' man page the synopsis I need is the following:

```
at [-V] -l [-o timeformat] [job ...]
```

where timeformat, according to the man page, is "strftime-like time format used for the job list". So I tried with the following command:

```
at -l -o "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

but keep getting: " at: invalid option -- 'o' "

Comment: I'm not sure why your command doesn't work. How about `atq -o "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`?

Comment: Yep, this works, thank you.

Comment: At least in the Debian implementation it looks like either a documentation bug, or a bug in the option parsing in the [at.c](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/at/-/blob/master/at.c) source code - if invoked as `atq` the option string is set to `"hq:Vo:"`; whereas if invoked as `at` with the `-l` option to just `"q:V"`